# gRaphael library compilation errors

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to use gRapahel library to create bar chart in my web site project. I need to use this library because standard ajax control doesn't work in IE8. I have added all *.js files to my project and I also added below lines to web.config file:

```
  <codeSubDirectories>
    <add directoryName="CSCode"/>
    <add directoryName="JSCode"/>
  </codeSubDirectories>
```

When I tried to compile my project I got 3 errors in App_SubCode_JSCode.qgb8opkc.6.js file:

> Only primitive types are allowed in a custom attribute
>
> Unknown custom attribute class or constructor
>
> Variable 'System' has not been declared

When I double click on the eroors it redirect me to the file with the erros which contains below lines:

```
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/// <autogenerated>
///     This code was generated by a tool.
///     Runtime Version: 4.0.30319.269
///
///     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if 
///     the code is regenerated.
/// </autogenerated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[assembly: System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("ASP.NET", "4.0.30319.272")]
[assembly: System.Security.SecurityRulesAttribute(System.Security.SecurityRuleSet.Level2)]
[assembly: System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute(".NETFramework,Version=v4.0")]
```

Could You plase help me fix this issue?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1:

I have added below code to create chart but I got error:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected

on line:

> ```
> var r = Raphael("InputHours"),
> ```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            var r = Raphael("InputHours"),
                    fin = function () {
                        this.flag = r.popup(this.bar.x, this.bar.y, this.bar.value || "0").insertBefore(this);
                    },
                    fout = function () {
                        this.flag.animate({ opacity: 0 }, 300, function () { this.remove(); });
                    },
                    fin2 = function () {
                        var y = [], res = [];
                        for (var i = this.bars.length; i--; ) {
                            y.push(this.bars[i].y);
                            res.push(this.bars[i].value || "0");
                        }
                        this.flag = r.popup(this.bars[0].x, Math.min.apply(Math, y), res.join(", ")).insertBefore(this);
                    },
                    fout2 = function () {
                        this.flag.animate({ opacity: 0 }, 300, function () { this.remove(); });
                    },
                    txtattr = { font: "12px sans-serif" };

            r.text(160, 10, "Single Series Chart").attr(txtattr);
            r.text(480, 10, "Multiline Series Stacked Chart").attr(txtattr);
            r.text(160, 250, "Multiple Series Chart").attr(txtattr);
            r.text(480, 250, "Multiline Series Stacked Chart\nColumn Hover").attr(txtattr);

            r.barchart(10, 10, 300, 220, [[55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 2, 10]]).hover(fin, fout);
            r.hbarchart(330, 10, 300, 220, [[55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 2, 10], [10, 2, 1, 5, 32, 13, 20, 55]], { stacked: true }).hover(fin, fout);
            r.hbarchart(10, 250, 300, 220, [[55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 2, 10], [10, 2, 1, 5, 32, 13, 20, 55]]).hover(fin, fout);
            var c = r.barchart(330, 250, 300, 220, [[55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 2, 10], [10, 2, 1, 5, 32, 13, 20, 55]], { stacked: true, type: "soft" }).hoverColumn(fin2, fout2);
        };



    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found sollution for that (I think). I moved CSCode outsede App_Code folder and I am able to compile the project.